# Upgrade Kubuntu from 20.04 to 20.04.02 LTS

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, updates, kubuntu

Hi what is the correct way to do this upgrade?
I did google and looked on youtube, but did not find any guide on that specific subject.

Comment: `sudo apt update` to update software lists (make your system fully aware of what updated packages are available), and `sudo apt full-upgrade` to upgrade your packages.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt update
```

to update software lists (*make your system fully aware of what updated packages are available*)

and

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

to upgrade your packages  (`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will perform the function as well, `dist-upgrade` was the operand for `apt-get` where `full-upgrade` is for the newer `apt`, either will work)